# React DND not working with Material UI Menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dnd

I am using `react-dnd` to implement drag and drop functionality in my code. The problem I am facing is that if I wrap my draggable components inside a `Menu` component. the drop functionality doesn't work while the drag works, but if I replace the `Menu` with a `div`, it works as expected.

Here's a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ShaleenAg/react-dnd-example) where the issue is demonstrated.

I have created a `Dummy` component which is essentially the `Knight` component and passed it in a mui `Menu` in `Board.tsx`. On opening the menu, the component is draggable as expected but not droppable.

Checkout to `without-mui-menu` branch, where I have replaced the whole menu thing with a div and it works as expected.

I went through react-dnd docs, and I just need to ensure there's a `dnd-provider` wrapped at the top level for it work, which I have done.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the issue?